# Gtest discover_tests failing in Github Actions: Process terminated due to timeout

Tags: macos, cmake, github-actions, googletest, ctest

I am using google-test(gtest) with CMake and running the unit tests as GitHub ci jobs for Linux and Mac. The Linux jobs pass successfully. However, I am getting an error for the mac runner.
The error is

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.1/share/cmake/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:77 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: '/Users/runner/work/splitwebp/build/test/splitwebp_tests'
    Result: Process terminated due to timeout
    Output:
      

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.1/share/cmake/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:173 (gtest_discover_tests_impl)
```

This is the `CMakelists.txt` for the tests directory

```
# CMake config file for unit tests
# Requiring V 3.10 for gtest_discover_tests
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
enable_testing()

# finds all .cpp files under this directory (./test) and add them to executable
file(GLOB_RECURSE tests "*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE source "../src/*.cpp")
add_executable(splitwebp_tests ${tests} ${source})

include_directories("../3rdparty/libwebp/include")

# Link gtest libraries
target_link_libraries(splitwebp_tests ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(splitwebp_tests webp webpdemux pthread)
target_link_libraries(splitwebp_tests gtest_main)

set(CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE 1)

# Find all tests in all .cpp files and convert to CTests
include(GoogleTest)

gtest_discover_tests(splitwebp_tests)
```

How do I fix the CI pipeline?

Comment: **Do not glob for sources without `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`**. Better yet, don't glob for sources at all.

Comment: Use `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `gtest_discover_tests(...)` is taking too long and thus getting timed out. The obvious solution is to increase the timeout limit.

The line

```
gtest_discover_tests(splitwebp_tests)
```

can be replaced with

```
gtest_discover_tests(splitwebp_tests PROPERTIES TIMEOUT 600)
```

Comment: Note: As of CMAKE 3.10.3 this is called `DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT` (see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/GoogleTest.html#command:gtest_discover_tests). It can be set as `gtest_discover_tests(splitwebp_tests DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT 30)`

Answer (score 0):

Rajdeep's answer was almost there for me. I had to use `TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT`:

```
gtest_discover_tests(splitwebp_tests PROPERTIES TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT 600)
```